# Can the Pagemap folder of processes in the Linux kernel be read(64bit per read) a finite number of times?

Tags: c, linux, memory, process, kernel

I'm trying to keep track of the number of writes per physical page in the file "proc/PID/pagemap".But the file is binary, and the size shown in the file properties is 0, and the following function reads 0 as well.

```
    struct stat buf;
    int iRet = fstat(fd, &buf);
    if(iRet == -1)
    {
       perror("fstat error");
       exit(-1);
    }
    printf("the size of file is : %ld\n", buf.st_size);
```

I write a monitor program to read data from a process's "pagemap" 64bit one time and record the 55-bit(soft dirty bit)to check if one page is written.Of course before doing this I cleared all soft dirty bit in a process's pagemap.This method is provided by linux kernel and my question during coding is that when I use file descriptor（also tried fstream pointer） to get the data from pagemap.My reading of pagemap ends only when the process I'm monitoring is finished, as if the file were infinite.I know the process's logical address mangement is dynamic but I want to know how could I count the write number properly.Should I read a part of this infinite file within a fixed time intervals?And how many items should I read?  T _ T.

Comment: Most files in */proc* show a size of 0 and their size should be ignored. The */proc/${PID}/pagemap* file has 8 bytes per page of virtual memory, but the virtual memory is very large on a 64-bit machine. The [Examining Process Page Tables](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/pagemap.html) section of the "The Linux kernel user’s and administrator’s guide" provides useful tips for examining ths file, for example: "Efficient users of this interface will use */proc/pid/maps* to determine which areas of memory are actually mapped and llseek to skip over unmapped regions."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like the following:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct pagemap_region {
    struct pagemap_region *next;
    uintptr_t              addr;    /* First address within region */
    uintptr_t              ends;    /* First address after region */
    size_t                 pages;   /* Number of pages in this region */
    uint64_t               page[];  /* 64-bit pagemap flags per page */
};

static void free_pagemaps(struct pagemap_region *list)
{
    while (list) {
        struct pagemap_region *curr = list;

        list = curr->next;

        curr->addr = 0;
        curr->ends = 0;
        curr->pages = 0;
        free(curr);
    }
}

struct pagemap_region *get_pagemaps(const pid_t pid)
{
    struct pagemap_region *list = NULL;
    size_t   page;
    char    *line_ptr = NULL;
    size_t   line_max = 256;
    ssize_t  line_len;
    FILE    *maps;
    int      n, fd;

    page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

    /* We reuse this for the input line buffer. */
    line_ptr = malloc(line_max);
    if (!line_ptr) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* First, fill it with the path to the map pseudo-file. */
    if (pid > 0)
        n = snprintf(line_ptr, line_max, "/proc/%d/maps", (int)pid);
    else
        n = snprintf(line_ptr, line_max, "/proc/self/maps");
    if (n < 0 || (size_t)n + 1 >= line_max) {
        free(line_ptr);
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Read the maps pseudo-file. */
    maps = fopen(line_ptr, "re"); /* Read-only, close-on-exec */
    if (!maps) {
        free(line_ptr);
        errno = ESRCH;
        return NULL;
    }
    while (1) {
        struct pagemap_region *curr;
        unsigned long  addr, ends;
        size_t pages;
        char *ptr, *end;

        line_len = getline(&line_ptr, &line_max, maps);
        if (line_len < 0)
            break;
 
        /* Start address of the region. */
        end = ptr = line_ptr;
        errno = 0;
        addr = strtoul(ptr, &end, 16);
        if (errno || end == ptr || *end != '-')
            break;

        /* End address of the region. */
        ptr = ++end;
        errno = 0;
        ends = strtoul(ptr, &end, 16);
        if (errno || end == ptr || *end != ' ')
            break;

        /* Number of pages in the region. */
        pages = (ends - addr) / page;
        if (addr + page * pages != ends || (addr % page) != 0)
            break;

        /* Allocate new region map. */
        curr = malloc(sizeof (struct pagemap_region) + pages * sizeof curr->page[0]);
        if (!curr)
            break;

        curr->addr = addr;
        curr->ends = ends;
        curr->pages = pages;

        /* Prepend to the region list. */
        curr->next = list;
        list = curr;
    }

    /* Any issues when reading the maps pseudo-file? */
    if (!feof(maps) || ferror(maps)) {
        fclose(maps);
        free(line_ptr);
        free_pagemaps(list);
        errno = EIO;
        return NULL;
    } else
    if (fclose(maps)) {
        free(line_ptr);
        free_pagemaps(list);
        errno = EIO;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Reuse the line buffer for the pagemap pseudo-file path */
    if (pid > 0) 
        n = snprintf(line_ptr, line_max, "/proc/%d/pagemap", (int)pid);
    else
        n = snprintf(line_ptr, line_max, "/proc/self/pagemap");
    if (n < 0 || (size_t)n + 1 >= line_max) {
        free(line_ptr);
        free_pagemaps(list);
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }
    do {
        fd = open(line_ptr, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_CLOEXEC);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        n = errno;
        free(line_ptr);
        free_pagemaps(list);
        errno = n;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Path no longer needed. */
    free(line_ptr);
    line_ptr = NULL;
    line_max = 0;

    /* Read each pagemap section. */
    for (struct pagemap_region *curr = list; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        off_t          offset = (size_t)(curr->addr / page) * (sizeof curr->page[0]);
        unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)&(curr->page[0]);
        size_t         need = curr->pages * sizeof curr->page[0];
        ssize_t        bytes;

        while (need > 0) {
            bytes = pread(fd, ptr, need, offset);
            if (bytes >= need)
                break;
            else
            if (bytes > 0) {
                ptr += bytes;
                offset += bytes;
                need -= bytes;
            } else
            if (bytes == 0) {
                /* Assume this is a region we can't access, like [VSYSCALL]; clear the rest of the bits. */
                memset(ptr, 0, need);
                break;
            } else
            if (bytes != -1 || errno != EINTR) {
                close(fd);
                free_pagemaps(list);
                errno = EIO;
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        free_pagemaps(list);
        errno = EIO;
        return NULL;
    }

    return list;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct pagemap_region *list, *curr;
    long  pid;
    char *end;

    if (argc != 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *argv0 = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[1]) ? argv[1] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv0);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s PID\n", argv0);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program prints the a map of the pages of process PID;\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "R for pages in RAM, S for pages in swap space, and . for others.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "You can use -1 for the PID of this process itself.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    end = argv[1];
    errno = 0;
    pid = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
    if (errno || end == argv[1] || *end) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid PID.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (pid != -1 && (pid < 1 || (long)(pid_t)pid != pid)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not a valid PID.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }        
    list = get_pagemaps(pid);
    if (!list) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (curr = list; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {       
        printf("Region %p - %p: %zu pages\n", (void *)(curr->addr), (void *)(curr->ends), curr->pages);
        for (uint64_t *map = curr->page; map < curr->page + curr->pages; map++) {
            if ((*map >> 63) & 1)
                putchar('R');
            else
            if ((*map >> 62) & 1)
                putchar('S');
            else
                putchar('.');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

We read `/proc/PID/maps` line by line, and construct a `struct pagemap_region` for each; this contains the start address, the end address, and the number of pages in the region.  (I didn't bother to support huge pages, though; if you do, consider parsing `/proc/PID/smaps` instead.  If a line begins with a `0`-`9` or lowercase `a`-`f`, it specifies an region; otherwise the line begins with a capital letter `A`-`Z` and specifies a property of that region.)

Each `struct pagemap_region` also contains room for the 64-bit pagemap value per page.  After the regions have been found/chosen – this one tries all –, the `/proc/PID/pagemap` file is opened, and the corresponding data read from the proper location using [`pread()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html), which works like `read()`, but also takes the file offset as an extra parameter.

Not all regions are accessible.  I do believe `[VSYSCALL]` is one of those, but being a kernel-userspace interface, its pagemap bits are uninteresting anyway.  Instead of removing such regions from the list, the above just clears the bits to zero.

This is not intended as a "do it exactly like this, just copy and paste this" answer, but as a suggestion of how to start going about this, perhaps exploring a bit, comparing the results or behaviour to your particular needs; a sort of a rough outline for an initial suggestion only.

Also, as I wrote it in a single sitting, it's likely got nasty bugs in it.  (If I knew where or for sure, I'd fix them; it's just that bugs happen.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, there is really a lot of interesting knowledge here, I have completed my program after learning for a while, it has completed the task of monitoring from one process to another to monitor the reading and writing times of the physical page statistics, if I have other questions later, we can also communicate！！